# linux Makefile syntax for blank lines in screen output

Tags: linux, makefile, screen

i have this makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

COMPILER_VERSION = "Intel 64 Compiler 16.0.0.109 Build 20150815"

SOURCES = \
ron1.f    \
ron2.f   \
ron3.f \
ron4.f

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o)

TARGET = mylib.a

FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -O3

linux: $(TARGET)
    @echo
    @echo "   " \
    ar r $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo
    @echo "   " \
    ranlib $(TARGET)
    @echo

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS):$(SOURCES)

cleanall:
    @echo
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
    @echo
clean:
    @echo
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
    @echo

.f.o:
    @echo "   " \
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $*.f
```

It results the below output:

```
prompt> make cleanall

rm -f ron1.o ron2.o ron3.o ron4.o mylib.a

prompt> make 
    gfortran -c -O3 ron1.f
    gfortran -c -O3 ron2.f
    gfortran -c -O3 ron3.f
    gfortran -c -O3 ron4.f

    ar r mylib.a ron1.o ron2.o ron3.o ron4.o

    ranlib mylib.a

prompt>
```

what i am looking to do is create a space between "prompt> make" and the first happening of `gfortran`.

and ideally i would like the output on the screen to first print out the contents of my COMPILER_VERSION variable before the first `gfortran` happens, such that the output would look like

```
prompt> make

    makefile written for: Intel 64 Compiler 16.0.0.109 Build 20150815

    gfortran -c -O3 ron1.f
    gfortran -c -O3 ron2.f
    gfortran -c -O3 ron3.f
    and so on...
```

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add to the  'linux' target some prerequisite like 'ECHO' here:

```
linux: ECHO $(TARGET)
     ar r $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
     @echo
     @echo "   " \
     ranlib $(TARGET)
     @echo

ECHO:
     @echo "\n\n\n\n Makefile written for the compiler version ${COMPILER_VERSION}"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a bunch, that worked.
your

```
linux: ECHO $(TARGET)
```

worked great, only thing i did different than what you typed was this syntax for ECHO:  which i placed at the bottom of the makefile.  It allowed me to space out the screen output exactly how i wanted it.

```
ECHO:
    @echo
    @echo "Makefile written for compiler version ${COMPILER_VERSION}"
    @echo
```

Comment: If he answered your question, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use echo with flag -e

```bash
@echo -e "\n"
```